# Starting X Server

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, bash-scripting, kde, xorg.conf

I installed Arch with KDE plasma. I want to start KDE without display manager and configured files by instructions from Arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE#From_the_console .But after configuring all that when I reboot it shows error

```
(II) modset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24,8 bpc.
(II) modset(60): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8bpc.
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 51: twm: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 52: xclock: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 53: xterm: command not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 55: exec: xterm: not found
/home/user/.xinitrc: line 54: xterm: command not found
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (II) server terminated successfully (0). Closing log files.
```

And then I am back to tty1 with login screen.

My .xinitrc file

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources 
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap 
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources 
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap
merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then

xrdb -merge $sysresources

fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then xmodmap $sysmodmap fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then

xrdb -merge "$userresources"

fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then xmodmap "$usermodmap" fi
start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then 
for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do 
[ -x "$f" ] && . "$f" 
done unset f 
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 & 
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 & 
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 & 
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
export DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma 
exec startplasma-x11
```

My .serverrc file

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@" vt$XDG_VTNR
```

My .bash_profile

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
if [ -z "${DISPLAY}" ] && [ "${XDG_VTNR}" -eq 1 ]; then
   exec startx
 fi
```

All these files are from /home/user .What am I doing Wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following lines from `~/.xinitrc`:

```
twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 & 
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 & 
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 & 
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
```

Also remember, lines after the first `exec` in a script will be silently ignored.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!